# Visual C# add batch file

Tags: c#, file, batch-file, launch

Is there any way to add a bat file to a visual studio project and launch it from there, instead of having 2 files? I have tried to add a batch file directly, but that did not work.

Comment: do you mean pre or post build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BAT files need to physically exist on the filesystem somewhere to be run, so doing so would only have the benefit of shipping only one file (the main .EXE) instead of both.

You can add the .BAT to the project, set the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy`. Then at runtime, when you want to execute it, you have to extract it to a temporary directory (not tested, but it should show the idea):

```
Stream batFileStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Project1.Test.bat");
FileStream tempFileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),"Test.bat"));
batFileStream.CopyTo(tempFileStream);
batFileStream.Close();
tempFileStream.Close();
```

Then run it from the temporary location:

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Test.bat"));
```

Another alternative approach can be to think to integrate the bat file functionality directly into the C# code the you're doing, and get rid of that file.